# Change background colour of parent div upon child hover in css?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, hover

I'm working on a web design assignment and I'm fairly uncomfortable with most css styles thus far, this task involves 3 coloured boxes in a div. I have to turn the white background of this div to the same colour of the box when the box is hovered.

HTML:

```
            <div id="t1_color_one" class="t1_colors" style="background: goldenrod;"></div>
            <div id="t1_color_two" class="t1_colors" style="background: lightgreen;"></div>
            <div id="t1_color_three" class="t1_colors" style="background: palevioletred;"></div>
```

Not trying to be "that guy" who asks stupid questions.. but I literally have no idea how to approach this. Thanks for any tips, greatly appreciated

Comment: So you want to change the parent's box colour when you hover over a child? I don't think you can do this with just CSS...yet. You may have to use javascript

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was trying to do. But rather the background of the div itself rather than the header. Thank you!

Comment: in case you're not sure as you are new to web design, the answers given have used the jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

here is working example, is this what you wanted >> http://jsfiddle.net/mbTBu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".t1_colors").hover(function(){
    var $c=$(this).css("background-color");
        $("#task1").css('background-color', $c);
  });
});
```

you can also use, `mouseover` & `mouseout` function to revert back the color.
http://jsfiddle.net/mbTBu/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think Jeremy means that the outside div id="task1" has to assume the color of the hovered inside div, so the solution is to use javascript:

```
$('.t1_colors').hover(function(){
   $('#task1').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
},
 function(){
   $('#task1').css('background-color', white);
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer in pure javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event)
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('t1_colors');
    var count_of_divs = divs.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<count_of_divs; i++)
    {
        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('task1').setAttribute('style', e.target.getAttribute('style'));
        }, false);

        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('task1').removeAttribute('style');
        }, false)
    }
}, false);
```

And you can check it in jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qpuaK/1/).